# How do I prove that the group $H$ is abelian in this question?

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, normal-subgroups

So I have a group $H$ and a direct product $H \times H$, which is also a group. Then, I am considering a set $A$ = {$(h,h)| h \in H$}. If $A \unlhd G \times G$, I have to show that $H$ is abelian.

My attempt:

So if I consider two arbitrary elements $h_1, h_2 \in H$, then $(h_1,h_1), (h_2,h_2) \in A$. Normality of $A$ means for any $(h,h') \in H \times H$, $(h_1,h_1).(h,h').(h_2,h_2)^{-1} \in A$, and after some steps, I get that $(h_1.h.h_2^{-1}, h_1.h'.h_2^{-1}) \in A$. I am confused as to what the next step is. Can anyone help me?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999629/normal-subgroups-prove-that-g-is-an-abelian-group

Comment: Thank you. I have voted to close this.

Comment: Can I just point out that you have the normality condition wrong. It should be $(h_1,h_2).(h,h).(h_1,h_2)^{-1} \in A$ for all $h,h_1,h_2 \in A$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes. thank you. It was a mistake while typing this.